# Populating options list with SQL

Tags: php, jquery, html, sql, ajax

So I'm currently in the process of trying to populate a select option list with some SQL using ajax and php. I've tried various different pieces of code however I still can't seem to crack it. Here is the ajax from the actual page its self...

```
$.ajax ({
    url:'orderentry_ajax.php',
    cache:false,
    data: {'request': 'getCounty', 'County': County},
    dataType: 'json',
    async: false,
    success: function(data)
    {
         $('#errMsg').html(data.errMsg);
         if(data.numRecs>0)
         {
                //divStr = divStr + data.custName + data.contactName + data.contactNumber + data.contactEmail;
                countyStr = countyStr + "<select>";
                for (var i=0; i<data.dataArray.length; i++)
                {
                   countyStr = countyStr + 
                      "<option value='data.dataArray[i].County'>" +
                      "Please Select" + data.dataArray[i].County + "</option>";
                }
                countyStr = countyStr + "</select>";
                $('#Countys').html(countyStr);
         }
   }
   //countyStr =     countyStr + data.dataArray[i].County +
});
```

As far as I'm concerned I did a similar exercise except I was populating the options list with another table, I've made the two pieces of ajax and php identical and it still doesnt seem to want to work. Here is the php from the ajax page....

```
if (trim($request) =='getCounty')
{
    //product update
    $County = $_REQUEST['County'];

    $errMsg = "";
    $con = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1', 'root', 'c0mplex', 'HRDatabase');
    //Check if connect..
    if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
    {
        $errMsg = 'Could not connect to Database.' . mysqli_connect_error();
    }
    else
    {
       // passed record for submit
       $qryStr = "SELECT * FROM county WHERE `county` = $County";
       //echo $qryStr;
       $result = mysqli_query($con, $qryStr);
       if (mysqli_error($con))
       {
          //echo (mysqli_error($con));
          $errFlg=1;
          $errMsg="Error during update, please try again. " . mysqli_error($con);
       }
       else
       {
           while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
           {
                $County = $row['county'];

                $rowing = array();
                $rowing['county'] = $County;
                $dataArray[] = $rowing;
            }
            $numRecs = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        }
    }
    mysqli_close($con);
    //to test error :
    // $errMsg="testing error";
    $info ->dataArray = $dataArray;
    $info ->numRecs = $numRecs;
    $info ->errMsg = $errMsg;
    $info ->County = $County;
    echo json_encode($info);
    //echo $msg;
```

}

The select option list has an ID on it of 'Countys' just to give a heads up. Any help would be greatly appreciated guys.

Cheers

Comment: what is your error, what happens, what should? give more information

Comment: First of all check whether the data is reaching the target php script and then check whether the data returned by php script is success value or any error, which would end up within `error` block of ajax call

Comment: My error is that the select list isn't being populated with the SQL table that is being called. I have worked through it and all seems fine so unsure as to why its not returning anything. Just gunna carry on debugging and will post up the results once completed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace below line in your ajax code for adding html dymically

```
countyStr = countyStr + "<option value='" + data.dataArray[i].County + "'>" + "Please Select" + data.dataArray[i].County + "</option>";
```

Comment: Thank you @Snehal however, unfortunately it has not changed anything. Its just plain bizarre how the exact same code works perfectly on another option list...

Comment: Is it throwing any error? May be the return value of ajax is empty

Comment: Nope, throwing no error at all. Although I am debugging with firebug which doesn't detect ajax and SQL but still should show me something but doesn't..

Comment: are you returning data from your function in json format or not?

Comment: What do you mean? All the code to do with this particular program is in the above box.

Comment: check for the return value of ajax. Check whether it is returning properly or not

Comment: I can't even do that as firebug isn't picking up anything

Comment: try with alert or console

Comment: No alerts are working as its ajax. I am currently working my way through debugging the SQL to see if anything is wrong with it.